# Consulta MySQL no reconoce comillas simples

Tags: mysql

Estimados estoy realizando una consulta en MySQL con parámetros, pero resulta ser que no me reconoce las comillas simples en los parámetros .

Si ejecuto la consulta de esta forma no me retorna ninguna fila

```
SET @valor = "'DPF OFF','EGR OFF'";
SELECT * FROM `servicios_adicionales` WHERE servicio IN(@valor)
```

Pero si la ejecuto de la siguiente forma, me devuelve las respectivas 2 filas

```
SELECT * FROM `servicios_adicionales` WHERE servicio IN('DPF OFF','EGR OFF')
```

Como puedo hacer que me reconozca las comillas ?

Answer (score 0):

Cuándo lanzas la consulta utilizando la variable, en realidad estás buscando un único valor, que *contiene* las comillas simples, es el equivalente a:

```
SELECT * FROM `servicios_adicionales` WHERE servicio IN('''DPF OFF'',''EGR OFF''')
```

Si quieres buscar dos valores, utiliza dos variables, donde ninguna debe contener las comillas, solo el valor a buscar, por ejemplo:

```
SET @valor1 = "DPF OFF";
SET @valor2 = "EGR OFF";
SELECT * FROM `servicios_adicionales` WHERE servicio IN(@valor1, @valor2)
```

Esto te traerá las 2 filas que estás buscando.

Si lo que buscas es traer un número indeterminado de variables, me te no que no puedes resolverlo lanzando una sentencia `in(@variable)`, pues el valor de `variable` no será interpretado como tal.

Una alternativa es valerte de la ejecución de SQL dinámico, por ejemplo:

```
SET @valor := "'DPF OFF','EGR OFF'";
set @sql := CONCAT('SELECT * FROM `servicios_adicionales` WHERE servicio IN(', @valor, ')');
PREPARE dynamic_statement FROM @sql;
EXECUTE dynamic_statement;
```

Answer (score 0):

Para este caso concreto podrías usar [`FIND_IN_SET`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set), que te permite usar tu variable tal y como la tienes definida. Si observas la sintaxis es distinta a `IN()`, porque **tienes que pasar dentro de la función el nombre de la columna y la variable**.

Por ejemplo:

---

```
SET @valor = "'DPF OFF','EGR OFF'";
SELECT * FROM `servicios_adicionales` WHERE FIND_IN_SET(servicio,@valor)
```